# How to clip overflow inside a BoxDecoration

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create a widget like a `CircleAvatar` that clips its child when it overflows (`CircleAvatar` only clip the image, not its child). Can I force a `BoxDecoration` to clip its child (like `overflow: hidden` in css)?

Consider I have these:

```
new Container(
  height: 50.0,
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    border: new Border.all(),
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
  ),
  child: new Container(
    color: Colors.orange,
    height: 20.0,
  ),
)
```

[image: rendered image]

I want orange box to be contained in blue circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`ClipOval`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html) class that can be used like this:

[image]

```
class ClipExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
      body: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                  child: new ClipOval(
            clipper:new MyClipper(),
                    child: new Container(
              color: Colors.red,

             height: 10.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect>{
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return new Rect.fromCircle(center: new Offset(0.0,0.0),
      radius:  50.0
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed `getClip` to `return new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);`. I think it's easier to understand.